# How to get std::chrono::system_clock::time_point from std::chrono::system_clock::time_point.time_since_epoch().count()?

Tags: c++, time, c++-chrono

I have a variable stored as a `long` a value from `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point.time_since_epoch().count()`.
I would now like to restore that `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` from the `long` variable.
So how can I convert a `long` to a `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`?

Comment: You need to convert your count to a duration and then the duration to a time point.

Comment: thanks, works (((more text to appease the stackoverflow gods)))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to convert the integral type to a `chrono::duration`, and then convert the `duration` to a `system_clock::time_point`.  But there's a catch:

`duration` is a template:

```
template <class Rep, class Period> class duration;
```

If you convert the integral type to the *wrong* `duration`, you'll get the wrong `time_point`.

Fortunately `system_clock` itself tells you the correct `duration` with its nested `duration` type:  `system_clock::duration`.  Additionally, each of these conversions is `explicit`.

So, in summary:

```
using namespace std::chrono;
system_clock::time_point tp{system_clock::duration{i}};
```

Comment: Why does it use curly brackets?

Comment: That's just a stylistic choice for the client.  I prefer `{}` to denote a construction.  `()` will also work just fine.

Comment: Lol I had no idea that was a thing in C++.